# How to find out what `*` operator do on two objects from some library (cirq)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-object, cirq

I just started using python cirq library and I came across the following line of code in the tutorial:

```py
XX_obs = cirq.X(q0) * cirq.X(q1)
```

I just want to find in the code what this `*` operator do on this two specific cirq objects. How to do so?

Comment: What does the documentation say about it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you need to find what the type of `cirq.X(q0)` is:

```
print(type(cirq.X(q0)))
```

Then look for the definition, in that class, of the method `__mul__`. The `__mul__` method of a class defines how an object behaves as a left operant of a multiplication operation.